# Wix - building files to subdirectories

Tags: wix, installation

I am new to WiX and am trying to get my install project to build certain files to a subdirectory of the build output path. For example, if my build output path is: bin\Debug, I would like certain files to be added to a subfolder here: bin\Debug\Images.

Is this possible please?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using a WiX project template with Visual Studio, MSBuild and/or SharpDevelop. If so, you have several options:

1. Use [XCOPY](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) in the [Post Build Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

   - flexible
   - somewhat easy to find in your project (on one of the project designer tabs)
   - not integrated well with the build system
2. Add the folder and files to your project folder, include them in your project and set the [Copy to Output Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on each file. Note: you can't set that property on a folder. The copying will preserve the folder structure but you have set the property on each file you want copied.

   - inflexible
   - very easy to find in your project (solution explorer and properties window)
3. Open the project file in a text editor and add MSBuild tasks such as [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3e54c37h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to the [AfterBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or other target. Note: To use VS to edit the project file, right click, select Unload Project, then right click and select Edit.

   - flexible
   - hard to find in your project (XML in the project file)
   - uses the build system

In the last case, I sometimes put a REM comment in the Post Build event to clue people into the fact that the project file has been customized.

Comment: Thanks that's great. I went with your option 3 and it works great. However, when it comes to running the install package, the installer can no longer locate the files I have moved in order to install them. Do I need to flag them somehow when I move them or am I missing something obvious please?

Comment: WiX's candle.exe doesn't include anything that's not in a WiX script (or extension). Though, it does provide the heat.exe tool to generate script for you. The [HarvestDirectory](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild%5Ctask_reference%5Cheatdirectory.html) task runs heat as part of the build.